# ngModel doesn't modify value

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying two way binding with ionic and angular but I cannot make it work. The value of the `formData` doesn't change when the form is completed.

Here is my HTML :

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submiter()">

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label position="stacked">Nom<ion-text color="danger">*</ion-text></ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="formData.name" name="name"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-button (click)="actu()"  expand="block" shape="round" >Refresh</ion-button>
  <ion-button type="submit"  expand="block" shape="round" >Save</ion-button>
</form>
```

And here is my Js :

```
export class Tab6Page{
  formData = {
    name : ""
  };

actu(){
    console.log(this.formData);
 }
}
```

When I click on the `Refresh` button after modifying the form, the console returns `name = ""`

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Use reactive forms. Read this https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: Have you tried a console.log in submitter method? If I does not help, try without ion with pure html tags. Ex: an ordinary input tag instead of ion- that would guide you to what’s wrong

Comment: I tried recreating this in  and it seems to work out okay. See stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-kmuusx  . I also recreated it with pure Angular , and classic inputs (not ion-input) and it worked as well. Maybe take a look and see if it still returns blank? 
Note, from first glance, the approach you are using inside a form might not be the best approach, but I don't know exactly what you're doing. Let me know if you're still having issues

Comment: I tried you code and it worked on stackblitz, so i deleted almost all of my code except everything related to routing and tried to run it, but it didn't work again. I think the problem may come from the routing. It's my first project with ionic so i may have messed that up, i'll take a look into it.